# сервер закрывается, после любого запроса с клиента

Tags: java, websocket, плагин

Первый раз пишу сюда, будьте снисходительны.
Пишу `websocket` сервер, его работоспособность проверяю хромовским плагином "WebSocket King Client", когда отправляю ЛЮБОЙ запрос серверу, он просто отключается.

```
package 123;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;
import org.springframework.web.socket.handler.TextWebSocketHandler;

@Component
public class SocketTextHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        String payload = message.getPayload();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(payload);
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("zzz " + jsonObject.get("user") + " xxxx"));
}
    }
```

```
package 123;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new SocketTextHandler(), "/user").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

}
```

Код app.js:

```
var ws;
function setConnected(connected) {
    $("#connect").prop("disabled", connected);
    $("#disconnect").prop("disabled", !connected);
}

function connect() {
    ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/user');
    ws.onmessage = function(data) {
        helloWorld(data.data);
    }
    setConnected(true);
}

function disconnect() {
    if (ws != null) {
        ws.close();
    }
    setConnected(false);
    console.log("Websocket is in disconnected state");
}

function sendData() {
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        'user' : $("#user").val()
    })
    ws.send(data);
}

function helloWorld(message) {
    $("#helloworldmessage").append(" " + message + "");
}

$(function() {
    $("form").on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#connect").click(function() {
        connect();
    });
    $("#disconnect").click(function() {
        disconnect();
    });
    $("#send").click(function() {
        sendData();
        });
        });
```

[image: Логи]

Как сделать, что бы сервер не только не отключался, но ещё и обрабатывал запрос и что-то отвечал клиенту?